# iiyama shows no signal after shutdown and longer sleep

Tags: display, displayport

I have iiyama G-Master GB3461WQSU connected to mac thought DisplayPort in dell's dock WD19TBS and PC's DisplayPort directly. Since day one an issue with signal detection occurs. After shutdown or longer inactivity, the display turns on for a brief moment and then detects no signal. I have to restart it with the power button, tap on the mouse or the keyboard. I tried with two others display port cables. I was using dell previously with the same setup without any issue.

[Here is the issue demonstartion.](https://stream.new/v/rmUI01A753XD024p402yVieHYqkg00CjyVcbu2F3eOlA2P)

What I can do other than send it back?